# How to construct MySQL view from query with UNIONs and sub-SELECTs

Tags: mysql, sql, view, union

I'm trying to construct what seems like a common report to show me which lottery tickets I've played have numbers matching one or more of the announced winning draw.  I have the below query which does exactly what I want from the SQL prompt.  However, I need to express this as a **VIEW** so my single ODBC connection can access the two separate databases but I can't figure out how to set up the separate sub-views without still needing the UNIONs.  Can anyone show me a better way?  Guidance appreciated.

```
SELECT record_id, GROUP_CONCAT(num ORDER BY num) nums
FROM (
      SELECT record_id, n1 num FROM LA.tickets UNION
      SELECT record_id, n2 num FROM LA.tickets UNION
      SELECT record_id, n3 num FROM LA.tickets UNION
      SELECT record_id, n4 num FROM LA.tickets UNION
      SELECT record_id, n5 num FROM LA.tickets
     ) foo
    WHERE num = ANY ((SELECT n1 n FROM L.draw WHERE record_id = 1) UNION
                     (SELECT n2 n FROM L.draw WHERE record_id = 1) UNION
                     (SELECT n3 n FROM L.draw WHERE record_id = 1) UNION
                     (SELECT n4 n FROM L.draw WHERE record_id = 1) UNION
                     (SELECT n5 n FROM L.draw WHERE record_id = 1)
                )
    GROUP BY record_id
    HAVING count(*) >= 1;
```

(In this scenario, record #1 of the 'draw' table contains the 5 most-recently drawn numbers.

Comment: Why can't you just add the `CREATE VIEW` stuff before this?

Comment: That's exactly my question -- I'm not sure how to do it.  I need a VIEW that provides the same result as the SELECT query but I'm unsure how to break it down into components. (The short answer to your question is that I'm being particularly thick right now.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, a quick google of `mysql create view` brings me to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html which gives me the syntax like this (just copy/pasting your `SELECT` statement verbatim):

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS
SELECT record_id, GROUP_CONCAT(num ORDER BY num) nums
FROM (
      SELECT record_id, n1 num FROM LA.tickets UNION
      SELECT record_id, n2 num FROM LA.tickets UNION
      SELECT record_id, n3 num FROM LA.tickets UNION
      SELECT record_id, n4 num FROM LA.tickets UNION
      SELECT record_id, n5 num FROM LA.tickets
     ) foo
    WHERE num = ANY ((SELECT n1 n FROM L.draw WHERE record_id = 1) UNION
                     (SELECT n2 n FROM L.draw WHERE record_id = 1) UNION
                     (SELECT n3 n FROM L.draw WHERE record_id = 1) UNION
                     (SELECT n4 n FROM L.draw WHERE record_id = 1) UNION
                     (SELECT n5 n FROM L.draw WHERE record_id = 1)
                )
    GROUP BY record_id
    HAVING count(*) >= 1;
```

Comment: No, it doesn't help at all, @peter-bowers.  I am familiar with the CREATE VIEW syntax.  What I was looking for is an alternate construction of the query logic that would be compatible with the constraints of a VIEW under MySQL.  To make this query work, I need to use constructs that are disallowed by a MySQL View.  

Ref: (http://bit.ly/1Caerpp)


The main problem I think is that I've got bad table structure.  I will re-visit this problem after giving it a normalization scrub.

Thanks for replying, though.